# How to add ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in field's DDL query via Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

What I want to achieve is that when someone adds movie in movies table, the `CreatedOn` and `UpdatedOn` columns to have to default value as `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. And when someone updates the same row, the value of `UpdatedOn` should be replaced with new `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

I'm using PostgreSQL as database and Entity Framework Core to create models.

I tried this as the model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ShowMe.Models;

public class Movie 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Show> Shows { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public DateOnly ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

And added this to `DbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ShowMe.Models;

namespace ShowMe.Data;

public class DataContext : DbContext 
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>()
            .Property(b => b.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasDefaultValueSql("gen_random_uuid()");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>()
            .Property(b => b.CreatedOn)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>()
            .Property(b => b.UpdatedOn)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
    }
}
```

Which generated this result in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE Movies
(
    Id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    Title text NOT NULL,
    Description text,
    Director text NOT NULL,
    Duration interval NOT NULL,
    ReleaseDate date NOT NULL,
    CreatedOn timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UpdatedOn timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

But what I want as result is ... this `UpdateOn` column to be generated like this, with `ON UPDATE` parameters added in the end.

```
UpdatedOn timestamp with time zone NOT NULL 
    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: It looks like a case for temporal tables (history tables). Postgres has this [extension](https://pgxn.org/dist/temporal_tables/). Entity Framework [works great](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/) with temporal tables in Sql Server. Check for yourself how it works in Postgresql.

Comment: You can manually add any commands to the generated migration code. [Customize migration code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#customize-migration-code).

Comment: Postgres does not have an `ON UPDATE` clause for a column, the exception being for a a FOREIGN KEY action. See [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). You will need to do this with a trigger.